# Time for control variables in Diff in Diff

Tags: difference-in-difference

I have a question about generating control variables in DID analysis.
Let's say I am interested in examining the effect of policy change (2015 reform). So I use the year 2014 and 2016 for the DID analysis. In this case, which year should I use for generating control variables? For example, education level/salary in 2014 or 2016?

Comment: Welcome. Do you also include 2015? Why did you only select one year before and one year after?

Comment: It's just an example. I have 2015 data; however, I thought the effect will appear after a certain time passes. If I want to examine the effect of the 2015 reform, I am wondering which year I need to use for generating control variables.